# How to expose a jax-ws which is located in a mule devkit connector?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, mule, mule-studio

I need to expose a jax-ws which is located in a mule devkit connector. Is there a way to do this operation or should I separate the jax-ws and mule-connecor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the fully qualified interface/class names in the `cxf:jaxws-service` element.

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF